# Call Paypal From Winforms app & PCI Compliance

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, paypal

My client has asked me to integrate my app to take credit/debit card payments from his customers using paypal. I have looked into using the Paypal REST API which seems to do what i need, however my client is worried about PCI compliance and wants all sensitive information to be entered using the paypal website only, and nothing in my app, so has asked me if i can simply open the paypal website payment section, just passing over basic info such as the customers address (who is making the purchase), amount to pay etc to save his operators time re-keying, and then for the operator to continue and fill in just the sensitive stuff such as the long number & expiry dates.

once the payment has been processed by paypal we obviously need to know the result i.e success/fail and any related information such as a payment reference ID, so i can then handle it in my app

is this possible, and if so could any kind soul please point me in the direction of an example so i can get going? i've had a look around and cant find what I need

I'm using VS2010 VB.NET but anything in C# I can easily translate

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately that isn't how Paypal work's, although you could integrate it in an `Asp.Net` application. If you did want to do it with `Winforms` you can use a `LinkLabel` to point to a `PayPal` BuyNow button email code. You could use the standard browser control or start-up the default browser with the link.

There are also different API's as well, not one is the same...

**Adaptive Payments**

The Adaptive Payments API allows merchants and developers to pay almost anyone and set up automated payments. They can create applications that manage payments, payment preapprovals, and refunds. They can also send money peer-to-peer, split payments in both parallel and chained models, accept guest payments, and schedule disbursements. The Adaptive Payments API works on multiple platforms including the web and mobile environments. Product Details...

**Button Manager**

Use the Button Manager APIs to dynamically create, manage, and edit large numbers of PayPal Payments Standard buttons. You can use the Button Manager API to manage any button you can create in your PayPal Profile. Product Details...

**Express Checkout**

Express Checkout allows merchants and developers to minimize the number of steps customers must complete when they checkout. Customers using Express Checkout pay on PayPal's secure site and return to the merchant's site to complete the transaction. It is designed for merchants who don't have an Internet Merchant Account for processing credit and debit card payments. Product Details...

**Mass Pay**

Merchants use the Mass Pay API to send money instantly to up to 250 recipients at once. To send payments to multiple recipients, merchants only need the recipient's PayPal account email address, the payment amount, and the currency code. Merchants can manually upload a file listing payments or create them programmatically using the Mass Pay API. Product Details...

**Payflow Gateway / PayPal Payments Pro**

Payflow is secure, open payment gateway. You can choose to have PayPal host the payment pages or have total control over the payment process. Payflow allows merchants to choose any Internet Merchant Account to accept debit or credit card payments and connect to any major processor. It also lets merchants accept PayPal and PayPal Credit® (formerly Bill Me Later® ) payments. Product Details...

**PayPal Payments Advanced**

Accept credit cards, PayPal, and PayPal Credit® online with PayPal Payments Advanced. This all-in-one solution offers an embedded checkout that keeps customers on the merchant's site and an Internet merchant account from PayPal. Plus, it's PCI compliant to help merchants manage their credit card security requirements.  Product Details...

**PayPal Payments Standard**

PayPal Payments Standard (also known as Website Payments Standard) allows merchants to add payment and checkout buttons to their website by simply cutting and pasting HTML. Merchants can use the buttons to securely accept credit card, debit card, or PayPal payments. Product Details...

**Recurring Billing**

Recurring Billing is the automated, flexible billing service that can be used with the Payflow Gateway. It allows you to bill customers on a schedule, reducing the hassle of manually processing regular payments. Whether it's an installment plan, membership fee or a subscription service, you can make sure you get paid regularly and on time. Product Details...

**Recurring Payments**

Monetizing your app through subscriptions, freemium or pay as you go models. With recurring payments, you can bill customers on a regular basis at intervals that you choose. Product Details...

**Website Payments Pro**

Website Payments Pro enables merchants and developers to accept credit cards, debit cards, and PayPal payments directly on their website. Website Payments Pro also includes Express Checkout and Virtual Terminal. Add-on services like Recurring Billing are also available. Product Details...

**Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution**

Website Payments Pro Hosted Solutions offers merchants a way to securely accept credit and debit card or PayPal payments without capturing or storing card information on their website. Payment information is collected by PayPal using an inline frame.

Please visit [**here**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/) to see more related information.

Comment: thanks for the info. if I had to go the api route what would you recommend?. ive looked at a sample using payflow and it seems simple enough to use - whats the most secure way and what should I worry about most on the PCI front

Comment: That's something that the Security Standards Council enforces. To help software vendors and others develop secure payment applications, the Council maintains the Payment Application Data Security Standard (PA-DSS) and a list of Validated Payment Applications. See more https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?association=PA-DSS there and https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/approved_companies_providers/validated_payment_applications.php?agree=true there.

Comment: Here's another good link to the document's: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/smb/what_to_secure.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look at `HttpClient`, as [the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) provides a decent way for C# code to

> send HTTP requests and receive HTTP responses from a resource
>   identified by a URI

You do not mention what version of .NET you are using so you may need to upgrade.

Your client is right to highlight the PCI issue, but without more details on your application and its use decent advice is difficult.

Comment: Hello @WinBase - you may be able to use HttpClient with .NET 4.0 via NuGet, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: Otherwise, if it's a new project can you use the latest version of .NET?

Comment: Im using net 4.0. my app stores no sensitive information such as the long number. how it will work is that a customer rings in with an order, the operator takes the card details and once paypal accepts it, the order is saved. im pretty sure my clients network is firewalled and secure and id planned to use the API but now have to rethink - what do others do? is using the REST API considered secure enough if you don't store card details?

Comment: @WinBase you can use `REST` just fine. All request and response are in `JSON` format... https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#api-operations there's more information there. Also you will never store the card details... well I should say you **shouldn't save the card details**.

Comment: @WinBase - I would recommend you download the docs from the PCI website - https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org. Depending on the situation you'll soon realise proper security basics are required and actually need to be documented, you can't be "pretty sure" about, for example, the firewall set-up.

Comment: @JoeR removed, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: "is using the REST API considered secure enough if you don't store card details?" Using the REST API is fine but there are security aspects - not storing the card details is just one of them.

Comment: @JoeR I would agree, that's why my comment below my answer told him to visit the doc's that Security Standards Council  enforces as you did :). If you looked through them, they are interesting and quite long/boring...